# Hi every one, i got this issue with docker-compose up: it's giving me this Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any

Tags: reactjs, docker-compose

version: '3.8'
services:
backend:
image: antoniopapa1991/backend
environment:
DB_HOST: db
DB_DATABASE: admin
DB_USERNAME: root
DB_PASSWORD: root
ports:
- 8000:8000
depends_on:
- db

db:
image: mysql:5.7.22
restart: always
environment:
MYSQL_DATABASE: admin
MYSQL_USER: root
MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
volumes:

- .dbdata:/var/lib/mysql

Answer (score 0):

It could be that there's just some wrong indentation in your docker-compose.yml file, what would lead to some wrong configuration. Is your docker-compose (including indentation) like this? Or is it somehow different?

```yaml
version: '3.8' 

services: 
  backend:
    image: antoniopapa1991/backend
    environment: 
      DB_HOST: db 
      DB_DATABASE: admin 
      DB_USERNAME: root 
      DB_PASSWORD: root 
    ports: 
      - 8000:8000 
    depends_on: 
      - db

  db: 
    image: mysql:5.7.22 
    restart: always 
    environment: 
      MYSQL_DATABASE: admin 
      MYSQL_USER: root 
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root 
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root 
    volumes:
      - .dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
```